# LiveData SwitchMap in ViewModel only returns data the first time

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, viewmodel, android-livedata

In my app there's a Fragment with a list of elements, and another Fragment showing the element details. When user clicks one of the elements in the list, app navigates to the details Fragment showing it's details. So when the users navigates to the details Fragment without selecting one element, should show no data.

In the details Fragment in onStart I check for arguments this way:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    arguments.let {
        if (it.selectedCurrent > 0) {
            viewModel.loadNewCurrent.value = it.selectedCurrent
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in the ViewModel:

```
val loadNewCurrent: SingleLiveEvent<Long> = SingleLiveEvent()

val currentSelected = loadNewCurrent.switchMap { value ->
    repository.getCurrentByKey(value)
}

val setShowData: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.map(currentSelected) {
    it != null && it.cityName?.isNotEmpty() ?: false
}
```

The repository function:

```
fun getCurrentByKey(key: Long): LiveData<CurrentEntity> {
    return currentWeatherDao.getCurrentByKey(key)
}
```

And the DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM currents WHERE `cityId` = :id")
fun getCurrentByKey(id: Long): LiveData<CurrentEntity>
```

The Repository and the Database seem to work fine. User can click in one of the elements, and app navigates and shows the details in the details Fragment. Problem comes when the user returns to the details Fragment without clicking one of the elements in the listFragment. In that case, fragment shows no data. Even if you just navigate to another fragment and come back to the details Fragment. Only way to show the details is clicking an element in the list.

I tried changing the SingleLiveEvent in ViewModel for MutableLiveData, but still the same problem occurs:

```
val loadNewCurrent: MutableLiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData()
```

My thoughts were, if LiveData in ViewModel didn't change, if user navigates back to detail Fragment, it should still show the previous loaded LiveData. But that's not the behaviour I'm having.

Am I doing something wrong in my code? If behaviour is as expected, how should I keep showing the same LiveData when launching details Fragment? I thought about keep the selected element ID on SharedPreferences and loading it everytime on details Fragment onStart. But I'm not sure if there could be a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Forgot to say, and it might be important, I'm using databinding between Fragment and ViewModel:

```
binding.viewModel = viewModel
```

Edit 2:

ViewModel Initialization:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CurrentFragment : Fragment() {

private val viewModel: CurrentViewModel by viewModels()

}

class CurrentViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
app: Application,
private val repository: Repository,
@Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
```

) : AndroidViewModel(app)

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, can you expand on this sentence it doesn't really make sense to me `So when the users navigates to the details Fragment without selecting one element, should show no data.` This code is from the details fragment right?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how the ViewModels are initialized

Comment: @DanielWilson app uses BottomNavigationView. So you can navigate to details Fragment via BottomNavigation, or clicking one element in the list Fragment. If you click an element in the list, app navigates and shows the element details correctly. But if you navigate away and come back, nothing is shown.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce edited and added the ViewModel initialization. As I said in Reddit, I'm almost sure LiveData was working as expected weeks ago. So I suppose I changed something that forced this behaviour. But can't see what exactly.

Comment: Try updating Hilt, your version is old

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you were right. Updated, changed deprecated components, but still the same problem. Just thinking, Roomdatabase, DAOs, Retrofit, all is annotated as Singleton. Repository, which receives these dependencies, too. Could be there the problem?

Comment: I would have thought the SingleLiveEvent is the problem - if `viewModel.loadNewCurrent.value = it.selectedCurrent` is called every time you want it to but a `currentSelected` value is observed only once then I think that's the only possibility. You could show the observe code as well. I don't know hilt but if it's the same vm instance then it can't propagate more than one single live event.

Comment: Fragment is recreated every time I navigate to another. I realized that's the normal functionality when using BottomNavigationView with NavHostFragment. I simply assumed the Fragments would remain stopped when leaving them. I'll try with this: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

Comment: If you want bottom tabs to stay alive, you'd have to do https://github.com/Zhuinden/BottomNavChildFragmentExample/blob/40d7b87ee77e96eae2b559b3b727609fb015198e/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/bottomnavfragmentexample/RootFragment.kt#L14-L98